# Accessing AWS S3 from within google GCP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform

We were doing most of our cloud processing (and still do) using AWS. However, we also now have some credits on GCP and would like to use and want to explore interoperability between the cloud providers.

In particular, I was wondering if it is possible to use AWS S3 from within GCP. I am not talking about migrating the data but whether there is some API which will allow AWS S3 to work seamlessly from within GCP. We have a lot of data and databases that are hosted on AWS S3 and would prefer to keep everything there as it still does the bulk of our compute.

I guess one way would be to transfer the AWS keys to the GCP VM and then use the `boto3` library to download content from AWS S3 but I was wondering if GCP, by itself, provides some other tools for this.

Comment: To access AWS S3 from GCP, use the same keys, APIs, tools and libraries that you would in AWS. I would not use Google S3 emulation libraries for S3 as these libraries are used to emulate S3 on Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: What particular services are you using within GCP which requires access to your AWS assets? Please be more descriptive in your ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an AWS perspective, an application running on GCP should appear *logically* as an on-premises computing environment.  This means that you should be able to leverage the services of AWS that can be invoked from an on-premises solution.  The GCP environment will have Internet connectivity to AWS which should be a pretty decent link.

In addition, there is a migration service which will move S3 storage to GCP GCS ... but this is distinct from what you were asking.

See also:

- [Getting started with Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/getting-started/)
- [Storage Transfer Service Overview](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/overview)

Comment: This is interesting. Thanks for the answer. Why should it be like an on premise application though? For example, I have a database on AWS that can only be accessed from within AWS. Are you saying GCP app accessing this database would be seen as an on premise app? Surely, I have to do something to set this up?

Comment: My thinking is that there is no "special" linkage between GCP and AWS as far as trusted networking goes on.  This means that the calls to AWS services from a GCP environment will likely by REST API calls that, from an AWS perspective, will appear to come in from "outside" AWS.  These I am calling "on-premises" apps (a call will either come from within AWS or from outside (on-premises)).  A call coming from GCP will likely come in from over the Internet or through a VPN (again likely over the Internet).  You will likely have to specify authentication for the call to succeed.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I thought as well. For S3, I can just use the `boto` libraries and it should be fine. For the datbase, I have to setup VPN access, which hopefully will be ok.