# Unload/Write data from Snowflake on GCP to AWS S3

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm new to Snowflake and couldn't really find an answer to this — What is the correct/recommended way to go about unloading data from Snowflake that is hosted on GCP to an AWS S3 bucket? Is it the same process as unloading from Snowflake that is already hosted on AWS, to S3, as highlighted [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-unload-s3.html)? Are there any additional security concerns or permissions that need to be granted?

How do you reconcile egress/ingress across different cloud providers in this case?

Can you simply connect and transfer data across clouds using JDBC/ODBC drivers for snowflake?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the correct/recommended way to go about unloading data from Snowflake that is hosted on GCP to an AWS S3 bucket?
> Is it the same process as unloading from Snowflake that is already hosted on AWS, to S3, as highlighted [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-unload-s3.html)?
> Are there any additional security concerns or permissions that need to be granted?

Yes, the link carries most of the steps required to setup an integration between any Snowflake deployment to your own AWS account, for performing an unload operation.

Snowflake [supports unloading across-clouds seamlessly as a use-case](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/billing-data-transfer.html#data-transfer-billing-use-cases), with [some egress charges](https://www.snowflake.com/pricing/pricing-guide/).

You will need to permit Snowflake [a supported mode of write access](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3-config.html) to the specific cloud storage account. Access to S3 from GCP will [occur over the internet (HTTPS)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58714803/13472370) from [GCP's data-center IPs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19434481/13472370), and the bucket policy should be permitted to allow such an access if it is currently restricted beyond authentication requirements.

> Can you simply connect and transfer data across clouds using JDBC/ODBC drivers for snowflake?

Yes. The statement execution is done by the Snowflake's [virtual warehouses](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/intro-key-concepts.html#query-processing) (i.e. service-side, not client-side) and [`COPY INTO <location>`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html) is a regular statement supported also by its JDBC/ODBC drivers.

Comment: Hi [Kirby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13472370/kirby) , thanks for your response! Just wanted to clarify a couple of points. You mentioned > setup an integration to any arbitrary AWS account for performing an unload operation. Not sure I follow this — in my use case, snowflake is on GCP. Wouldn't the unload be done by snowflake's warehouse from GCP? > bucket policy should be permitted to allow such an access Do you mean that the bucket should be set up such that it can allow public internet access?