# GetObject from AWS s3 using GCP SA auth and store it localy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gsutil, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to access the object in the s3 bucket with the GCP SA and store the s3 object localy.
I tried using the below commands , But got  `gslib.exception.HashMismatchException md5 signature computed for local file`

```
gsutil cp s3://bucket-name/image.png ./

gcloud storage cp s3://bucket/image.png ./
```

I can listObjects in the s3 bucket using the below command :

```
gsutil ls s3://bucket-name/image.png
```

I can download ( getObject) from the aws cli using the below command :

```
aws s3api get-object --bucket bucket-name  --key image.png abc.png
```

Is there a way that is possible to store the s3 object locally by using the gcp sa auth credentials and gcp cli?
I found some ways to do this but got stuck with the above error.

1. Automate file transfer from AWS S3 to GCP Cloud storage ( transfer jobs ). (Not the way to achieve the end goal).
2. Access with [Federated Identity](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/source-amazon-s3#federated_identity) ( I followed this one ).

Are there any other ways it is possible to achieve/fix this ?

Thank you.

Comment: May be the way mentioned at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58714257/accessing-aws-s3-from-within-google-gcp#:~:text=I%20guess%20one%20way%20would%20be%20to%20transfer%20the%20AWS%20keys%20to%20the%20GCP%20VM%20and%20then%20use%20the%20boto3%20library%20to%20download%20content%20from%20AWS%20S3%20but%20I%20was%20wondering%20if%20GCP%2C%20by%20itself%2C%20provides%20some%20other%20tools%20for%20this.) by tweaking it acccordong to requirement?

Comment: As stated here on AWS’ [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonResponseHeaders.html) Objects encrypted by SSE-C or SSE-KMS have ETags that are not an MD5 digest of their object data.To provide a workaround for this situation, you will need to disable the MD5 verification process in gsutil. Please note that by doing so, there would be no guarantee that the data received is the same as the source data.Here is how to do it, by adding the check_hashes tag `gsutil -o GSUtil:check_hashes=never cp s3://…`

Comment: This works! , but yes the integrity is lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated here on AWS’ [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonResponseHeaders.html) Objects encrypted by SSE-C or SSE-KMS have ETags that are not an MD5 digest of their object data.

The workaround for this situation, you will need to disable the MD5 verification process in gsutil. Please note that by doing so, there would be no guarantee that the data received is the same as the source data.

please follow the below steps,by adding the check_hashes tag:

```
gsutil -o GSUtil:check_hashes=never cp s3://…
```

If the data integrity is essential, you may refer to using awscli along with the gsutil to [copy S3 object to a local file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html).
This will be basically done on a local machine where both aws and gcloud cli are installed then you can get data from aws s3 bucket and store it in local machines’s folder and then upload that data to GCS using gcp cli. Or you might use a 3rd party client to transfer the data for you but will have the additional risk of giving them access to your AWS and GCP resources.